# Kentico webpart visibility

Tags: kentico

i'm trying to hide an editable text webpart if it's empty. Tried some JS methods which aren't elegent (the webpart has a bottom border, so there is a flicker). I then came across this post: [Kentico 7 hide editable text if it's empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20709968/kentico-7-hide-editable-text-if-its-empty/32097158#32097158)

Any reason why this won't work in Kentico 9? It's hiding my webpart regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In v8 and > you want to use the below syntax as the `CMSContext.CurrentDocument` has been deprecated.

```
{% (ViewMode != "LiveSite") || (CurrentDocument.editabletext != "") %}
```

Where you see `.editabletext` this is the code name of your editable text webpart.

Comment: It fails if there is code in the HTML Envelope. I remove the HTML i have there, and it's good.

Comment: Ok, i created a new layout, wrapped the CMS tag in the HTML i needed, and used your code example as is. I did not change .editabletext to match my Web part control ID. It's working.

Comment: Slight correction. I was cached, so '.editabletext' was changed. Cheers!