# Kentico macro to hide widget zone / web part zone if it contains no web parts

Tags: macros, web-parts, kentico, kentico-12

My widget zone (a webpartzone) has before/after HTML to fit it into the layout of the page.  However, if editors choose not to include any web parts, then I would like to set the zone's visible field to false.  Any idea how to access the current zone's child count in a macro?

Answer (score 1):

You can hide web parts by checking if the [web part has content or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20709968/kentico-7-hide-editable-text-if-its-empty/32097158#32097158).  But I don't believe you can set the visibility of a zone based on the zone having content or not.